# Bootstrap 3.0 grid responsivity inside div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I looked around on the internet, but found no satisfying answer. I am new to using the Bootstrap 3 grid, which I enjoy a lot. However, for an animation on a page I am creating, I would like to shrink a row to some small width and while this animation plays, I want the Bootstrap grid to do its work on this div instead of on the entire viewport. Does anyone know a way to do this? I found the following suggestion by someone who was also wondering about this:

[Bootstrap grid system responisve utility in resizable divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019059/bootstrap-grid-system-responisve-utility-in-resizable-divs)

However, I would prefer a CSS solution for this.